# SwiftUI Charts: How to center the Y-axis labels on each horizontal bar in a bar chart?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm using the new SwiftUI Charts framework to display data in a vertical bar chart, but I'm having trouble centering the Y-axis date labels on each bar:

```
struct ChartEntry: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let labelDate: Date
    let amount: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let chartContent: [ChartEntry]
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(chartContent) { entry in
                BarMark(x: .value("Value", entry.amount),
                        y: .value("Hour Label", entry.labelDate, unit: .hour))
            }
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: chartContent.map{$0.labelDate}) { data in
                AxisValueLabel()
            }
        }
        .chartXScale(domain: 0...50)
    }
}
```

This code generates a chart with Y-axis date labels aligned to the bottom of the bars (I populated the chartContent object with sample entries):

[image]

I want to center the labels on each bar.

I've tried `AxisValueLabel(centered: true)`. It moved all the Y-axis date labels down in an apparent random amount. Now they are misaligned and in the wrong place. Additionally, the first row is missing a label:

[image]

I've also tried `AxisMarks(preset: .aligned)`, but it doesn't change anything.

How can I center the Y-axis date labels on each bar?

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75487523/swiftui-charts-cutting-off-last-value-with-centered-axisvaluelabel) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240487/swift-charts-will-not-display-the-last-x-axis-axisvaluelabel-with-axismarks) question, but these solutions do not solve the problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This problem only appears to be happening when the Y-axis label is a Date object, so I found a workaround: I converted each Date label into a String and the problem went away. 
It's not an answer to my question, that's why I'm posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Swift Charts requires an understanding of how labels should be paired and aligned with the bars. Therefore, in addition to specifying unit: `.hour` for the y-value, you might also need to configure `values: .stride(by: .hour)` within the AxisMarks.

> ```
>       .chartYAxis {
>         AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: .stride(by: .hour)) { _ in
>             AxisValueLabel(centered: true)
>           }
>       }
> ```

This should work.

[image]